# Configure VS Code output window for python to jump to last line of output window?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I am sorry if the question doesn't make sense, I didn't really know how to phrase it properly.

What I am trying to achieve is similar to how it works in the command prompt when running a python file. When I run a python file from the command prompt, the command prompt window will jump to the last outputted line during the running of the program, so what is currently being outputted is always visible. However in my current VS Code set up, the output window will not jump to the last line as it is printed, and I have to scroll through the output window to see what is happening with the program.

I am currently using the latest version of VS Code and using the code-runner extension as well. Please let me know if what I am asking does not really make sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, I would like to answer it.

To **Auto-Scroll** to the last output, you can just click on the `Lock Icon` near the `Clear Console` icon.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I missed that.